# Magento2 - issue when importing bundle products

Tags: magento2.2, importexport, bug, bundle-product

This is a Magento 2.2.2 project... last season (it was 2.1.* then) we achieved to import this catalog using native **import/export** module (after several hours playing with .csv files)

But this season, when trying to register new products, we've found a big issue

Import process seem to work fine, but bundle products are not saleable in frontend (products return false when checking `isSaleable()`)

There is **no stock management** in this project, and we have double checked status values for this products (both in backoffice & database), so it smells like another Magento2 bug (introduced at some 2.2 version). Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Effectively, it was a bug. It seems last working version was **2.1.12**, and it should be fixed back in **2.3.***

The workaround posted here https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/12330#issuecomment-384627832 worked like a charm

> Insert the missing bundle relations: INSERT IGNORE INTO catalog_product_relation SELECT parent_product_id,product_id FROM catalog_product_bundle_selection
>
> Reindex stock and price indexes